# Why I add a new item to a List<string> it's adding it to the bottom of the list?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First time its adding it to the top I see the List:

1
2
3
4
5

But after the first time on the next times a new item is added to the bottom and I want it to be on top.
Instead to be number 6 the new item should be 1 and number 6.

This is how I build the List each time adding 3 items:

```
newText.Add(t[i]);
newText.Add(dateTime[i]);
newText.Add(string.Empty);
```

Then I make a filter to match for specific strings(words) :

```
FilterWords.CheckIfWordsExistInList(newText);

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using mshtml;
using System.IO;


namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    class FilterWords
    {
        public static void CheckIfWordsExistInList(List<string> newText)
        {
            // start at the bottom in the first line "that matters" and go down by 3
            for (int x = newText.Count - 3; x >= 0; x -= 3)
            {
                // check if the line contains any of the words specified
                if (!WordsList.words.Any(w => newText[x].Contains(w)) || newText[x] == "")
                {
                    // remove the checked line as well as the next two if not
                    newText.RemoveRange(x, 3);
                }
            }

            ExtractLinks.CheckIfResponseContainWords();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the I have a string that I assign to it the items from the List newText:

```
private void CombindedStringFix()
{
    combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newText);
    string[] ss = combindedString.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" },
                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int i = 0; i < ss.Length; i++)
        ss[i] = ss[i].Trim();

    combindedString = String.Join("\n", ss);

    string[] lines = combindedString.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" },
             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    combindedString = String.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
         if (i % 2 == 0)
            combindedString += Environment.NewLine;

         combindedString += lines[i].Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    scroller1.TextToScroll = combindedString;
    m_textToScroll.Text = combindedString;
    m_textToScroll.Text = m_textToScroll.Text.TrimStart();
}
```

But each time a new text is added I see it in the scroller1 and in m_textToScroll at the bottom.

Comment: Would using a `Stack<string>` help? Or is it that you actually want to add a specific, limited set of values and should be using a strongly-typed model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just looking to add an item at a specific position in the list then just use insert(index,object) rather than add. So in your case you would add it to index 0.

This then shifts all the other items down the list.

Add by default just sticks it on the end of the list for you.